# Gmail App Script ANYONE access

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am writting a Google app script addon for Gmail. The addon is in a domain account and I want to make it accessible to anyone, not only for the same domain users.

I have added this to my appscript.json file:

> "executionApi": {
>       "access": "ANYONE"
>   },

These lines, should set access for ANYONE to the addon, but when I try to deploy a new version, I get an error message that says that my domain admin has disabled ANYONE access.

I am the domain administrator, so I have checked if the security parameters are corrects:

- API Reference is enabled
- Less secure apps access enabled

Does anyone have idea of any other configuration parameter that I can change in order to allow ANYONE access?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to check your process [here in creating Gmail Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart#top_of_page). Also, check your Manifest base on the specification discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests). From there you will be able to identify if you are lacking some configuration or added some that is not stated.

Comment: In the link that you have provided, there are no access definition, so if i remove the access parameter, the script only would be accesible for my domain users. I need to change this, in order to let anyone to access my addon

Comment: Where did you find / learn the "access" definition?

Comment: I have created two apps scripts, one is a Gmail app and the other is a webapp. When i published, the first time, from manifest, the webapp script, the process asked for permissions and added this  parameter to my manifest. This works fine on my personal account, wich is a free gmail account, but when i try to recreate the development in my domain account, doesn't accept access = ANYONE, i only can use access = DOMAIN. If i understand well, this means that only my domain users can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the Google Cloud Support team gave me the solution to this problem. When you create a webapp App script, your files are stored in Google Drive, so you must check this option in the admin panel of the google domain (admin.google.com):

- Go to "**Applications**"
- Select "**G-Suite**"
- Select "**Drive and Docs**"
- Enter in the sharing configurations
- Check the option to allow users to publish files in the web

With this option checked, the error has disapeared and now i can publish my script with ANYONE acccess.

Comment: I guess this functionality is limited to enterprise account. With my free account, I see an error message: "admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com"